# How to convert an std::string to C-style string

Tags: c++, string, cstring, stdstring

I am programming in C++.

As basic as this question is I cannot seem to find an answer for it anywhere. So here is the problem:

I want to create a C-style string however I want to put an integer variable i into the string. So naturally, I used a stream:

```
stringstream foo;
foo
                << "blah blah blah blah... i = " 
                << i
                << " blah blah... ";
```

However, I need to somehow get a C-style string to pass to a function (turns out foo.str() returns an std::string). So this is technically a three part question --

1) How do I convert std::string to a C-style string?

2) Is there a way to get a C-style string from a stringstream?

3) Is there a way to use a C-style string directly (without using stringstreams) to construct a string with an integer variable in it?

Comment: The easiest way would be to just make an `itos` function using a stream, and use `itos (564).c_str()`, where the function returns `foo.str()`.

Comment: `sprintf()` and the buffer-overflow-safe `snprintf()` will populate a cstring formatted as you specify.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1) How do I convert std::string to a C-style string?

Simply call `string.c_str()` to get a `char const*`. If you need a *mutable* _C-style_ string then make a copy. The returned *C string* will be valid as long as you don't call any *non-const* function of `string`.

> 2) Is there a way to get a C-style string from a stringstream?

There is, simply `strstream.str().c_str()`. The returned *C string* will be valid only until the end of the expression that contains it, that means that is valid to use it as a function argument but not to be stored in a variable for later access.

> 3) Is there a way to use a C-style string directly (without using stringstreams) to construct a string with an integer variable in it?

There is the *C way*, using `sprintf` and the like.

Answer (score 3):

You got halfway there. You need `foo.str().c_str();`

1. `your_string.c-str()` -- but this doesn't really convert, it just gives you a pointer to a buffer that (temporarily) holds the same content as the string.
2. Yes, above, `foo.str().c_str()`.
3. Yes, but you're generally better off avoiding such things. You'd basically be in the "real programmers can write C in any language" trap.

Comment: I've heard that joke about FORTRAN, but since when did it become hip to bash on C :-(.

Comment: @jedwards: I'm not bashing on C at all -- but I think it's better to pick one or the other than write bits of C++ with decidedly non-C++ idioms mixed in.

Answer (score -1):

1. this is realy simple

   ```
   #include <afx.h>
   std::string s("Hello");
   CString cs(s.c_str());
   ```
2. no
3. yo can use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) to format a c-style string