# Trouble using a string with the sprintf() function

Tags: c++, string, shared-memory

I'm hoping that this will be a pretty basic problem that is maybe due to my lack of understanding a lot of the C++ Win32 API utlities.

Anyway, I'm having some trouble with the `sprintf()` function. I had no problem using it with a string like this:

```
//memory is a void pointer that maps a file to shared memory
sprintf((char *)memory, "Shared memory message"); //Write to shared memory
```

But when I try to use a `string` variable it doesn't work....

```
sprintf((char *)memory, str_var); //Write to shared memory
```

I get an error that says: `no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists`. I am not even able to fix this by type casting, like I did with `memory`.

This seems pretty inconsistent. What am I doing wrong, and how do I give it a value that it will accept?

Comment: std::string cannot be converted to const char*, use the .c_str() member method to convert it

Comment: try to learn difference between string and c-style string.


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958437/how-to-convert-an-stdstring-to-c-style-string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958437/how-to-convert-an-stdstring-to-c-style-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iff you need `sprintf`, you need to pass a `const char*`:

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

So e.g.

```
sprintf((char *)memory, str_var.c_str());
```